# Does windows media creation tool on copy any of my personal files on USB ( like photos, etc.)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, bootable-media, media-creation-tool

My friend asked me if I could make bootable W10 USB for him. I used media creation tool option. Now because it makes it from windows on my pc I want to know if my personal files are safe (is there any way some are copied with windows, or it just takes system related files). I did not make any kind of back up, only windows 10 bootable USB using Windows media creation tool from their web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Media Creation Tool downloads a complete fresh Windows installation image straight from Microsoft and writes that fresh image either to an USB stick or to an ISO image (that can be used to burn an installation DVD).

It will NOT copy any files of the computer used to generate the install media.
So your personal files will NOT end up on the USB stick.

It WILL wipe the USB stick completely before putting the installation image on it.
So if there were any files on the stick before you used the Media Creator Tool they are now gone.